# Python regex for integers combination from 01000 to 95999

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to build a regular expression that would match french zipcodes in python.

A french zipcode is composed of the department code (from 01 to 95) followed by a 3 digits subregion (let's say 000 to 999) to be large.

I'm trying this one : `0[1-9][0-9]{3}$|[1-8][0-9]{4}$|9[0-5][0-9]{3}$`

I split the problem in three

01xxx to 09xxx, then 1xxxx to 8xxxx, then 90xxx to 95xxx

Any idea to make it better ?

EDIT :

(0[1-9][0-9]{3}$)|([1-8][0-9]{4}$)|(9[0-5][0-9]{3}$) : This will only match if my input number has only 5 digits.

And my final version will be :
    ^((0[1-9]{1})|([1-8]{1}[0-9]{1})|9[0-5]{1})[0-9]{3}$
This "factorize" the [0,9]{3} endpart.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iwehaLye1-upGSGQ)

Comment: Comma `,` in `[1,9]`. Mistake? (intended `[1-9]`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can(/*should*/**must**) test your regex on [the official list of french postal codes](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-officielle-des-codes-postaux/).

```
import collections
codes = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in open('code_postaux_v201410.csv'):
    if not line[:1].isdigit():
        continue
    row = line.strip().split(';')
    codes[row[2]]+= [row[1].strip()]

def test_failures(regexp):
    r = re.compile(regexp)
    return [code for code in codes if not r.match(code)]

len(test_failures(r'^((0[1-9]{1})|([1-8]{1}[0-9]{1})|9[0-5]{1})[0-9]{3}$'))
# 283 !

# not ideal, because it does not guarantee the input to be an existing one
len(test_failures(r'^0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-8]|2A|2B[0-9]{3}$'))
# but at least no miss!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use a regex like `\d{5}` to first match 00000 to 100000

to first match everything, then verify each match by checking whether the string as integer is between 1000 and 96000.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think there were some typos in your example.

 (instead of `[1,9]` probably should be `[1-9]`)

Besides that the only (minor) improvement would be to not repeat the end pattern.

```
(0[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-5])[0-9]{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone already suggested https://www.debuggex.com

They actually have a solution for the French Postal code there :).

Comment: I asked that because I'm using the most important postal company in France to handle shipment for an selling website.
The thing is that the API asks for that special regex I needed.